# Overload instance[key] += val

Tags: python, jython

I am writing a Java collection class that is meant to be used with Jython. I want end users to be able to manipulate the collection this way:

```java
myCollection = MyJavaCollection()
myCollection[0] += 10.;
a = myCollection[0]; //a = 10
myCollection[0] += 20.;
b = myCollection[0]; //b = 20
```

What I find in the Python documentation is the following methods:

- `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods should do the job for bracket operator overloading.
- `__iadd__` method is the good candidate for the `+=`.

How can I mix both to do want I want ?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Sets are unhashable and cannot be used this way, and even if you mean `myCollection` is a list containing only a 2-element set, I cannot understand how you mean it to look after this operation is complete.

Comment: edited the example to explain results I expect. Removed the index as list and replaced it by a simple int.

Comment: Thanks, editors. This is a nice-looking question now!

Comment: Wait, do you want a list index, or just a single index? With a single index a simple list already does what you are asking for, except that you seem to want the value at `myCollection[0]` to reset to zero once it's been read? Otherwise `b = 30` no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `myCollection[0] += 10.;` will really be interpreted something like:

```
myCollection.__setitem__(0,  myCollection.__getitem__(0).__iadd__(10.))
```

Therefore, to make this work you need to implement:

- `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` on `MyJavaCollection`; and
- `__iadd__` (or `__add__`, which Python will fall back to if `__iadd__` isn't implemented) on *whatever `.__getitem__` is going to return*, not `MyJavaCollection` itself - if it will return something that already implements addition, like the `float`s in your example, you're fine.

---

A quick demonstration:

```
>>> class Container(object):

    def __init__(self, contained):
        self.contained = contained

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print "Container.__getitem__"
        return self.contained

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        print "Container.__setitem__"
        self.contained = val


>>> class Contained(object):

    def __add__(self, other):
        print "Contained.__add__"
        return "foo"


>>> test = Container(Contained())
>>> test[0] += 1
Container.__getitem__
Contained.__add__
Container.__setitem__
>>> test.contained
'foo'
```

Comment: Small addendum, python will still try to invoke `Contained.__iadd__`, only resorting to `Contained.__add__` if `__iadd__` was not present. In this way if a `Container` had a list then the list would be mutated inplace rather than a new list being created.

Answer (score 2):

Your original question had a list passed as the index, so I wrote this assuming that you wanted to access the `(i, j)`th element of a 2D list. You can do that by defining your class with something like:

```
class MyJavaCollection:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        """
        Returns the item at index (i, j) given an index list [i, j].
        """
        return self.values[indices[0]][indices[1]]

    def __setitem__(self, indices, value):
        """
        Sets the (i, j)th item to the input value given an input
        index list [i, j].
        """
        self.values[indices[0]][indices[1]] = value
```

Here you are overloading the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods to retrieve or set the `(i, j)`th element in your `values` list when you pass a list of indices `[i, j]`. If your values are just numbers, then the syntax `myCollection([1, 1]) += 10` will add `10` to `values[1][1]`.

As stated in another answer, if you are not simply storing numbers in your object, then you may need to overwrite the `__add__` or `__iadd__` method on whatever class your data comprises to get the behavior that you want.

Testing my example class:

```
>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>> my_list[1][1]
   5
>> my_collect = MyJavaCollection(my_list)
>> my_collect[[1, 1]]
   5
>> my_collect[[1, 1]] += 5
>> my_collect[[1, 1]]
   10
```

The [documentation on special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) gives you everything you could want to know about special methods like this. It can be a good place to search if you are not sure what method you may need to overload.